# How can I add block to a form element?

Tags: magento2, category, forms, ui-form

I want to customize `category_form.xml` in such a way so that, I can add custom block to the form element [say: Category Name].

Is there a way to add custom block to the Element?

Comment: You have to add only custom block or also add phtml for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add htmlcontent for calling block inside the category_form.xml

First you have to override category_form.xml in your module and then you put below code to call custom block.

```
<htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">ZealMage\CustomerDiscount\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\Tab\AssignCustomers</argument>
            </htmlContent>
```

And if you call block with template then used below code for that.

```
<htmlContent name="html_content">
            <block class="ZealMage\CustomerDiscount\Block\Adminhtml\Edit" name="action_baseurl" template="ZealMage_CustomerDiscount::config.phtml"/>
        </htmlContent>
```

Still you have any query let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dharmendra. I try to use "htmlcontent" along with "fieldset>>Field". Say for an example, in below code I want to add my custom block.

```
<field name="name" sortOrder="30" formElement="input">
        <settings>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Category Name</label>
        </settings>
```

Is there any way?